# Custom Control Binding not working

Tags: c#, ios, mvvmcross

i had created a custom numbpad control for ios and now try to bind it with MVVMCross to my ViewModel. But it doesn't work the value is always null within the ViewModel.

The Code of the NumberPad is:

```
    [Register("NumberPad")]
public partial class NumberPad : UIView
{

    public string Text {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public NumberPad(IntPtr h): base(h)
    {
        //SetUp ();         
    }

    public NumberPad (RectangleF frame) : base(frame)
    {
        SetUp ();

    }

    public NumberPad ()
    {           
        //SetUp ();         
    }

    void SetUp ()
    {
        var arr = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib ("NumberPad", this, null);
        var v = Runtime.GetNSObject (arr.ValueAt (0)) as UIView;
        v.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, Frame.Width, Frame.Height);
        AddSubview (v);

        Number0.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
        Number1.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
        Number2.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
        Number3.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
        Number4.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
        Number5.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
        Number6.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
        Number7.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
        Number8.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
        Number9.TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;

    }

    void HandleTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int tag = ((UIButton)sender).Tag;

        if (tag >= 0 && tag <= 9) {
            Text = String.Format("{0}{1}",Text,tag);
        } else if (tag == 10 && Text.Length > 0) {
            Text = Text + Text.Substring (0, Text.Length - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And Binding like this:

```
set.Bind(numberPad).For(vm => vm.Text).To (vm => vm.Password);
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want MvvmCross to automatically pick up changes in a property like:

```
public string Text {
    get;
    set;
}
```

then you **must** give MvvmCross some way of knowing that the property has changed value. The easiest way to do this is to simply provide an event with a conventional name and to raise this change when the text changes - e.g.:

```
public event EventHandler TextChanged;

private string _text;
public string Text {
    get { return _text; }
    set {  _text = value; TextChanged.Raise(this);  }
}
```

For more on custom controls and custom bindings, see N=18, 19, 20 and 28 in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.co.uk/